# How can I split a quantity for e.g. weight is 85 kg, into value=85 and unit=kg separately in typescript (angular)

Tags: javascript

Without using regex, any solution to this problem ?
How can I obtain in unit and value from a quantity separately?

Comment: It is certainly doable without regex, but why would you put that restriction on yourself? It'd just get more complicated.

Comment: Please, provide the code you have so far.

Comment: You've almost swapped the role of title and question body entirely.  Please describe the entire problem in the question body.  Then, afterwards, give it a nice brief title. Also, you have to let us know what you've tried and where you got stuck.  Otherwise we have no idea what level of understanding of the problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

If you know you have space between everytime, as your example `85 kg` you can just split it like this

```js
const someString ="75 kg";
const [value, unit] = someString.split(" ");
return {value, unit};
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really an Angular question or a Typescript question.  Anything you do would be *equivalent* to a regex, but you could do this, for example:

```
const separateIntoUnits = (s: string): {value: number; units: string} => {
  const {v, u} = _.groupBy(s, n=> ((n >= '0' && n<='9') ? 'u': 'v'));
  return {value: Number(v.join('')), units: u.join() };
}
```

(This uses lodash's `[groupBy][1]` function for convenience.}

Comment: So complex code for such an easy task...

Comment: @Random — It’s a parser, never an easy task.

Comment: @Drenai — sorry, last-minute change...

Comment: ChristianMoen's answer looks like an easy code for an easy task... Way easier to understant/debug :)

Comment: @Random — easier code for an easier task.  If there is no built-in delimiter (the space), it becomes harder.  If you have a better way to solve the *given* problem (splitting 'NNCC' into ['NN', 'CC']), go ahead and post it.

Answer (score -1):

Asumming you don't know what you asking for, as it makes no sense to not use regex for this task.

```
   const unit = string.replace(/(\D)/g, ""); //Remove any digits
   const value = string.replace(/(\d)/g, ""); //Remove anything not digits
```

(there is better ways of doing this but this should be very simple to understand.)

Tip https://regexr.com/ is very useful to get it right when doing regex

Comment: "it makes no sense to not use regex", actually it does. You should avoid using regex if you can do it an other way.

Comment: @Random is there anywhere I can find information about that? (cant find any)
From what I manage to find reasons to not use regex is.
1. There is already a better way to get the information, for instance a parser.
2. The regex causes alot of load.
3. The rules of the data is not known, making it impossible to create a correct regex. (But in this case a regex is usually your best option anyway)
4. I guess Microsoft screwed upp regex as well so if you are in MS universe I would not trust it. Different languages handles regex differently, this might be a problem.

Comment: Well, @ChristianMoen's answer does it with 1 simple line instead of 2 regex, which should be more performant, so there is a reason not to use regex. I'm not saying your solution is not good. I'm just pointing out your "it makes no sense" phrase, which is too strict. You may say "I would personnaly use regex", or "I don't see any reason to not use regex" or anything more opinion based ;)